# Notify room owners when a user is kicked

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, notifications, kick-mute

Currently when a user is kicked from the chatroom room owners other than the one who kicked the user do not get notified of the kick.

This is problematic since it leaves us with two options:

- Notify the room when the user is kicked with a message. We have initially started doing that but it turned out users who were put publicly in the troublemaker position usually did not recover well. They entered the room when the mute was over and made more trouble.
- Not notify the room when a user is kicked. I've found that this helps a lot in recovery - usually starting a separate room with the user and exchanging 3-4 messages with them explaining the situation after a kick works well. This however means kicks are unsupervised, unmonitored and we don't have any idea if/when a user was kicked and by whom.

I propose that in order to solve this problem when a user is kicked from the room all room owners get an alert about it - either via the flag interface (blue alert) or a ping (green alert). This would be in addition to the mod flag being raised at the third kick of a user.

This would help us moderate the chat rooms better.

Here is [our discussion about the issue at the JS room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21008911#21008911) if anyone cares.

Comment: I think the interface used for invitations is a better indicator.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240434/can-we-get-log-messages-for-kicks

Comment: Yes, the invitation style notification would be perfect for this!

Comment: Please for the love of Mother, yes.

Comment: It's been a few months and the need for this feature has only become more obvious to regular chat users. I can come up with examples if it's truly necessary but I don't think I need to paint the picture of no one knowing what's going on with a problematic user.

Comment: There have been several cases where not knowing when a user has been kicked has caused issues with room owners (accidentally kicking again for the same offense, etc). This would really help solidify room owner moderation coordination.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is now completed. Any room owners or moderators *present in the room* when someone is kicked will be notified via one of those drop-down thingies:

[image: user has been kicked from room by kicker and cannot return for 1 minute]

This is NOT a permanent log; it exists only to give context to those who might also be preparing themselves to deal with a problem user.

Comment: Thank you so much for listening. This is a much needed feature.

Answer (score 10):

I think this is a fantastic idea and should be implemented. No one appears to have voiced any criticism of this idea.

Pulling from the comments.

> I think the interface used for invitations is a better indicator. –  Florian Margaine Jan 16 at 23:00"

> "Yes, the invitation style notification would be perfect for this! –  ɥʇǝS Jan 16 at 23:46"

And the best:

> "Please for the love of Mother, yes. –  Sterling Archer Jan 21 at 15:52"

Comment: 2 upvotes, bounty, in two minutes??

Comment: @ShadowWizard http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22721861#22721861